# How to move object when plotting without axes change?

Tags: plotting

```
ContourPlot[
Power[(x), 3/2] - Power[1.65, 0.5]*(x) + ((y))^2 == 
 0, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
MaxRecursion -> 1]
```

I can get [image]

Then I need to rotate and move this object to the below position
[image]

I know `RotationMatrix`can rotate,but how to move object with mathematica function?

Comment: The parameter `b` is not defined in your code. I assume `b = 1/3`?

Comment: @JEM_Mosig,`b` just make plot bigger, I edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is more clear if we rewrite your code as follows:

```
b = 1/3;
f[{x_, y_}] := Power[b*(x), 3/2] - Power[1.65, 0.5]*b*(x) + (b*(y))^2;

ContourPlot[f[{x, y}] == 0, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, 
  MaxRecursion -> 1
]
```

This produces your original figure, but we have defined an explicit function `f`, for convenience.
Now we can define the geometric transformation that rotates your figure about `{0,0}` by 105° and then moves it by `{-10, 5}` in the (x,y) plane.

```
tf = RotationTransform[105 Degree, {0, 0}]@*TranslationTransform[-{-10, 5}];
```

Now

```
ContourPlot[f[tf@{x, y}] == 0, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, 
  MaxRecursion -> 1
]
```

gives your desired result.

Comment: I cannot repeat your script,nothing display.

Comment: @kitty, what version are you using? If you are using a version older than 10, try this instead: `ContourPlot[f[AffineTransform[{RotationMatrix[105 °], {10, -5}}] @ {x, y}] == 0 // Evaluate, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}, PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 1]`

Comment: @J.M.version 11.2.I guess something wrong in your `f[{x_, y_}] := Power[b*(x), 3/2] - Power[1.65, 0.5]*b*(x) + (b*(y))^2;`

Comment: Did you define `b = 1/3`? I just copied your code there.