# How to rotate and move plot in PolarPlot function without axes change?

Tags: plotting

```
PolarPlot[Exp[θ], {θ, 0, 10}]
```

I get plot as below:

[image: spiral]

If I need to rotate and move this object as below:

[image: transformed spiral]

What function can I use?

I ask this question because I need to know the general method to rotate and move object. I ask [a similar question about `ContourPlot`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/167316/how-to-move-object-when-plotting-without-axes-change), it seemed there's no general method for all plot function.

Comment: What you show doesn't look like a simple rotation. Can you be more precise about specifying the geometric transform you actually want?

Comment: Does this answer both of your questions? [rotated PolarPlot with Show](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44748/5478)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use `ParametricPlot[]` instead, things are easier:

```
ParametricPlot[Composition[TranslationTransform[{-3000, -100}], RotationTransform[-120 °]][
               Exp[θ] AngleVector[θ]] // Evaluate, {θ, 0, 10}]
```

[image: translated and rotated spiral]

Note that multiplying your polar function with `AngleVector[θ]` (equivalently, `{Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}`) converts it into an equivalent form that can be used by `ParametricPlot[]`.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that it is not a good idea to try to apply geometric transformations to a `Graphics` object. One should better attack the geometric objects (the graphics primitives such as `GraphicsComplex`, `Polygon`, `Line`, `Point`, ...) *inside* a `Graphics` objects.

Let's start with the graphic you supplied. (Note that I specify a concise `PlotRange` in order to prevent myself from running into some problems with inconsistencies among the handling `Options` different plot types.)

```
g = PolarPlot[Exp[θ], {θ, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {{-100, 100}, {-100, 100}}]
```

[image]

The relevant primitive here is `Line` as can be seen from the `InputForm` of `g`. In the following I `Rotate` anything that evaluates to `True` under `RegionQ` by `Pi/3` about the point `{0,0}` and `Translate` it afterwards by `{0,10}`. Thanks to [JEM_Mosig](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/35390) for pointing out that `RegionQ` can be used.

```
 g /. {x_?RegionQ :> Translate[Rotate[x, Pi/3, {0, 0}], {0,10}]}
```

[image]

This should work with slight modifications for arbitrary plot types (also 3D plots) and for all graphics primitives.

Comment: Nice :-) Using `x_?RegionQ` instead of `x_Line` is a bit more general.

Comment: @JEM_Mosig Yeah, good idea. Actually I am spelunking for a `GraphicsPrimitiveQ` function... Haven't been successful, yet... =/

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher,`g = PolarPlot[Abs[t]/3, {t, -Pi, Pi}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]` doesn't work in your script `g /. {x_RegionQ :> Translate[Rotate[x, Pi/3, {0, 0}], {0,10}]}`

Comment: @kittygirl Oops. Typo. It has to be `x_?RegionQ` (with a question mark).